# How to load local mp4 video file using EMBED or OBJECT html tags? Is it possible?

Tags: html, object, audio, video, embed

**1) embed**

**2) object**

I can use the "embed" tag and "object" tag to load youtube videos, but I want to use these tags to load local video files... but nothing is loaded on my HTML page.

Please, I cannot load an mp4 local video file.... so, how can I do it using embed and object to load local video files?

Comment: Please, include what you have tried and be more specific on what you want to achieve instead of what you cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <video src="videos/yourvideo.mp4" width=320px  height=240px controls poster="display-image.jpg">
    </video>
```

Just make a new folder with the name "video", and put your ".mp4" video file in it. And btw. you don´t need a Display-image.